# Add static route to AWS VPC

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I have a VPC 10.0.0.0/16. It has subnetwork 10.0.4.0/22. In that subnetwork i have openvpn server with clients in 10.8.0.0/24. How can i add a route to my openvpn clients from ec2 instances. I need that my servers in 10.0.4.0/22 can connect to openvpn clients to 10.8.0.0/24. Something like this:

```
route add -net 10.8.0.0/24 via 10.0.4.23
```

(ip of my openvpn instance is 10.0.4.23)

How can i do it in aws console? Should i reboot instances after changes to obtain new route?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a route pointed at the VPN concentrator's ENI. You also need to disable SRC/DST check on the VPN instance.